# Concurrent batch jobs writing logs to database

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, cron, batch-processing, amazon-sqs

My production system has nearly 170 Ctrl-M jobs(essentially cron jobs) running every day. These jobs are weaved together(by creating dependencies) to perform ETL operations. eg: Ctrl-M(scheduler like CRON) almost always start with a shell script, which then executes a bunch of python, hive scripts or map-reduce jobs in a specific order.

I am trying to implement logging into each of these processes to be able to better monitor the tasks and the pipelines in whole. The logs would be used to build a monitoring dashboard.

Currently I have implemented logging using a central wrapper which would be called by each of the processes to log information. This wrapper in turn opens up a teradata connection EACH time and calls a teradata stored procedure to write into a teradata table.

This works fine for now. But in my case, multiple concurrent processes (spawning even more parallel child processes) run at the same time and I have started experiencing dropped connections while doing some load testing. Below is an approach I have been thinking about:

- Make processes write to some kind of message queues(eg: AWS sqs). A listener would pick data from these message queues asynchronously and then batch write to teradata.
- Using files or some structure to perform batch writing to teradata db.

I would definitely like to hear your thoughts on that or any other better approaches. Eventually the end point of logging will be shifted to redshift and hence thinking in the lines of AWS SQS queues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shellter.. This is definitely not a software recommendation question. I honestly feel this is a concurrent programming/architecture problem. Thanks for your opinion though :)

Comment: while you may  get some useful ideas from other users, this Q is (IHMO) off-topic per definitions in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I offered Software Recommendations as a possibly better forum to help you get some answers, but really, most S.E. sites avoid architecture as "too board", or "opionion based". As I said, an interesting problem, but not a coding Q as defined for S.O. I'll be happy for you if someone does answer, so good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I think Kinesis firehose is the perfect solution for this. Setting up a the firehose stream is incredibly quick and easy to configure, very inexpensive and will stream your data to s3 bucket of your choice and optionally stream your logs directly to redshift.

If redshift is your end goal (or even just s3), kinesis firehose couldn't make it easier.

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/

> Amazon Kinesis Firehose is the easiest way to load streaming data into
>   AWS. It can capture and automatically load streaming data into Amazon
>   S3 and Amazon Redshift, enabling near real-time analytics with
>   existing business intelligence tools and dashboards you’re already
>   using today. It is a fully managed service that automatically scales
>   to match the throughput of your data and requires no ongoing
>   administration. It can also batch, compress, and encrypt the data
>   before loading it, minimizing the amount of storage used at the
>   destination and increasing security. You can easily create a Firehose
>   delivery stream from the AWS Management Console, configure it with a
>   few clicks, and start sending data to the stream from hundreds of
>   thousands of data sources to be loaded continuously to AWS – all in
>   just a few minutes.